# Jetpack Compose LazyColumn not scrolling when inside XML ScrollView

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-scrollview, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I am attempting to implement a functional LazyColumn within a ScrollView in XML. Unfortunately, the nestedScroll functionality of the LazyColumn is not working as expected. I have provided a simplified project on GitHub, specifically designed to showcase this problem: https://github.com/emoiroux/TestNestedScrolljetpackCompose.

I have tried Modifier.nestedScroll(rememberNestedScrollInteropConnection()) on the LazyColumn.
I was expecting the LazyColumn to work with the parent XML scrollView.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.